# Transformation of variables in Poisson distribution

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, discrete-data

If $X$ is a random variable which follows $\text{Poisson}(u)$ distribution then what is the variance of $X^2$?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we can use some tricks to find the variance of $X^2$ for $X$ with a $Poisson(u)$

Let $Y=X^2$

$Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-[E(Y)]^2=E(X^4)-[E(X^2)]^2$

For a Poisson distribution we know that $Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=u$  and $E(X)=u$

$\therefore E(X^2)=u+u^2$

Next we need to find $E(X^4)$, we need some tricks here.

We first to find $E(X^3)$

We will first calculate the Expectation of $E[X(X-1)(X-2)]$

$E[X(X-1)(X-2)]=\sum_{i \ge 0} x(x-1)(x-2)\frac{ u^xe^{-u}}{x!}\\=u^3e^{-u}\sum_{x \ge 3}\frac{u^{x-3}}{(x-3)!}=u^3e^{-u}*e^u=u^3$

(can you see the tricks above?)

Next

$E[X(X-1)(X-2)]=E(X^3-3X^2+2X)=E(X^3)-3E(X^2)+2E(X)=u^3$

We already know the $E(X^2)$ and $E(X)$ so we now can calculate $E(X^3)$

$E(X^3)=u^3+3(u+u^2)-2u=u^3+3u^2+u$

Ok, use the same tricks you can calculate $E(X^4)$, I would like to leave it for yourself to calculate it. But I will tell you the result.(you will use $E(X^3)$ when you calculate $E(X^4)$)

$E(X^4)=u^4+6u^3+7u^2+u$

$\therefore Var(X^2)=Var(Y)=E(X^4)-E(X^2)^2\\=(u^4+6u^3+7u^2+u)-(u+u^2)^2\\=4u^3+6u^2+u$